# Custom Single Page Portfolio Theme

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm thinking about creating single page portfolio theme, but I'm a little confused on how this would be done based on the different sections on the single page.

I'll explain what I would like to do and hopefully someone can help me figure this out. I'm just looking for guidance on what I should do to handle the different sections (maybe custom post types?)

1. Slider
2. Portfolio ( 4 Columns -- -- -- -- )
3. About ( 2 Columns -- ------)
4. Contact ( 2 Columns ------ -- )
5. Footer / Social Links

If it is too much work for me I'll just pay to have this created, so if interested please leave a contact email and I will get back to you

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page editor switch to HTML mode and wrap each section of content around divs you want to be a column.

```
<div class="col2w col2a">Col 1</div>
<div class="col2w col2b">Col 2</div>

<div class="col3w col3a">Col 1</div>
<div class="col3w col3b">Col 2</div>
<div class="col3w col3c">Col 3</div>
```

Next use CSS to style them to look like columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just

1. add a simple page and
2. set it as the front page in your admin settings
3. then assign a page template and add your code there:

   ```
   <?php
   /*
   Template Name: Single Page Template
   */
   // add your code here
   ```